# Spark write partition in hdfs having files of the same size

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large table in hdfs which has millions of rows per day. My goal is to write files of the same size, forcing a maximum number of rows to be written in a single file. This is what I am doing to achieve that (spark 2.3.1). For example

```
 spark.sql("select * from dataToWrite where yyyy_mm_dd = '2019-10-01'")
      .write
      .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000000)
      .format("orc")
      .partitionBy("yyyy_mm_dd")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save(s"hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data'")
```

After that I check hdfs and I get

```
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     33.8 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00097-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    596.0 M 2019-10-17 15:23 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00098-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    594.2 M 2019-10-17 15:29 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00098-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    589.4 M 2019-10-17 15:37 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00098-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c002.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    101.6 M 2019-10-17 15:38 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00098-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c003.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    592.1 M 2019-10-17 15:16 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00099-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     33.8 M 2019-10-17 15:17 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00099-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    595.8 M 2019-10-17 15:19 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00100-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     33.6 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00100-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    595.2 M 2019-10-17 15:19 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00101-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     32.7 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00101-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    595.1 M 2019-10-17 15:19 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00102-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     33.9 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00102-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    594.5 M 2019-10-17 15:19 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00103-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     34.6 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00103-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    592.0 M 2019-10-17 15:23 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00104-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    592.2 M 2019-10-17 15:28 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00104-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     67.6 M 2019-10-17 15:29 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00104-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c002.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    595.4 M 2019-10-17 15:24 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00105-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     33.1 M 2019-10-17 15:24 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00105-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive    597.2 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00106-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c000.snappy.orc
 -rw-rw-rw-   3 aliparoti hive     35.0 M 2019-10-17 15:20 /user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data/yyyy_mm_dd=2019-10-01/part-00106-9fb1ec99-c7c9-4d41-a183-ca58d18bbe8f.c001.snappy.orc
```

Somehow I get these weird file sizes. Do you know what can I do to achieve chunks of the same size? Do I maybe need a custom partitioner?

Comment: Seems like you have a skewed dataset, try adding `repartition(X)` step before writing. Now it should be about finding optimal partitions number

Comment: Check if you have  NULLs in your data

Comment: no nulls @KSNidhin shouldn't the partition by do the job as well @Gelerion?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is:

Assume that you have 100,05,000 rows of data equally distributed among 10 partitions. So, each partition will now hold 10,00,500 rows. Considering each executor core will be working on each partition, while executing write task, each executor writes 1 file with 10,00,000 rows and another with 500 rows. So, ideally there will be 10 equally sized large files and 10 equally sized small files. This is whats happening in your case.

Solution:

You need to perform a `count` and then based on that value you need to come to a number such that rows in each file is somewhere around 10,00,000. Use this number in `repartition` method and you will find equal sized files in the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't understand much. What are these numbers? Also all these rows belong to the same partition

Comment: The numbers are just an example to throw some light on how can you get such output when one of the files is smaller in size and the other one larger. Can you please try the solution that I have suggested and let me know the output.

Answer (score 1):

Inefficient, as only one core will be doing the job, but should give you expected result

```
spark.sql("select * from dataToWrite where yyyy_mm_dd = '2019-10-01'")
    .repartition("yyyy_mm_dd")
    .write
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000000)
    .format("orc")
    .partitionBy("yyyy_mm_dd")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save(s"hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/aliparoti.db/test_data'")
```

Comment: why only 1 core would do the job? aren't the repartition and partition doing the same thing?

Comment: there is only data for 1 day: 2019-10-01 and `.repartition("yyyy_mm_dd")` will move all this data to one partition.